# Spawning Sugar Cane

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't find any sugar cane anywhere on my map.

How do I make sugar cane spawn if I currently have none?

Comment: create new world and there you will find all new resources(added after update).

Comment: Related: [When surveying a new world what do I need to check exists that I can't create later?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82743/)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Since the world isn't infinite, and sugar cane is a natural resource, you can't create it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also get it when you make the nether reactor

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can't spawn it. Answer found from this post on the *Minecraft Forums*
[Link to the post.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/164316-making-sugar-cane-spawn/)

**-Ways of finding it or getting it**

Now each world has every material in a x amount of quantities. This means if you continue following the coast you should find sugar cane. Once you got your first sugar cane, plant it and expand the farm. If your lazy to look you can go into custom mode and open up your inventory and just get a stack of 64 sugar cane or whatever amount you need and go back to normal mode, and start you farm.

Comment: Not all worlds in Pocket Edition will have sugar cane since it is randomly generated and PE worlds are not infinite.